# Fetch api in useEffect to make an infinite scroll but execute in wrong order

Tags: asynchronous, react-hooks, async-await, fetch, algolia

I am trying to fetch data from Algolia database (index.search is similar to fetch) in useEffect,but then I find the order it execute is not the way I think.I console "queryNews1", "queryNews2", ..."queryNews6" in async function queryNews(), and I think they will sequentially print out in console(see image below). But I find that after queryNews2, it "jump out" of queryNews() but execute the code outside queryNews(), after console.log("5"), it go back to execute "queryNews3".

I guess it's an asychronous issue, so I wrap queryNews() inside an another async function `const getData = async () => { await queryNews(keyword); };` and call getData(), but it's still execute in wrong way.Why and does anybody know how to fix that??

Sorry for my bad English!

mobile in the console is writing in `articleState.map(() => { console.log("mobile"); return (); });`

[console results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Octz0.png)

```
const [articleState, setArticles] = useState<ArticleType[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("1");

    if (windowResized === "large" || windowResized === undefined) return;

    let isFetching = false;
    let isPaging = true;
    let paging = 0;

    console.log("2");

    async function queryNews(input: string) {
      console.log("queryNews1");

      isFetching = true;

      setIsLoading(true);
      setSearchState(true);
      setPageOnLoad(true);

      console.log("queryNews2");

      const resp = await index.search(`${input}`, {
        page: paging,
      });
      
      console.log("queryNews3");

      const hits = resp?.hits as ArticleType[];

      setTotalArticle(resp?.nbHits);
      
      console.log("queryNews4");

      setArticles((prev) => [...prev, ...hits]);
            
      console.log("queryNews5");

      setIsLoading(false);
            
      console.log("queryNews6");

      paging = paging + 1;
      if (paging === resp?.nbPages) {
        isPaging = false;
        setScrolling(true);
        return;
      }

      console.log("queryNews7");

      isFetching = false;

      setSearchState(false);
      setPageOnLoad(false);

      console.log("queryNews8");
    }

    console.log("3");

    async function scrollHandler(e: WheelEvent) {
      if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >=
        document.body.offsetHeight - 100) {
        if (isFetching || !isPaging) return;

        console.log("scrollHandler");
        getData();
      }
    }

    const getData = async () => {
      await queryNews(keyword);
    };

    getData()
   
    console.log("4");

    window.addEventListener("wheel", scrollHandler);
    console.log("5");

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("wheel", scrollHandler);
    };
  }, [keyword, setSearchState, windowResized]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `getData()` without awaiting it. Because of this, it'll run parallel to the top level `useEffect` code. This isn't an issue, if `getData()` is the last line of code in the function.

But if you do need that initial `getData()` to complete before hitting `console.log("4");`, you could do this:

```
    getData()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("4");

        window.addEventListener("wheel", scrollHandler);
        console.log("5");
      });
```

From `console.log("4");` will run after the call to `getData()`.

**Clarifier on `async` and `.then()`**

With this function in mind:

```
const doSomething = async () => {
  // Do something async
  console.log('during');
});
```

The following:

```
const asyncFunc = async () => {
  console.log('before');

  await doSomething();

  console.log('after');
});
```

Is equivalent to:

```
const asyncFunc = () => {
  console.log('before');

  doSomething()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('after');
    });
});
```

Either will return:

```
before
during
after
```

However, if you used:

```
const syncFunc =() => {
  console.log('before');

  doSomething();

  console.log('after');
});
```

Becasue I have not awaited `doSomething()`, I have created a race condition, whereby `during` and `after` could be returned in a different order depending on how long it took the async code to complete. Because the `syncFunc` script will continue running as soon as `doSomething` has been called (but crucially, has not finished).

So you could get:

```
before
after
during
```

Wrapping `await queryNews(keyword);` in another function called `getData()` does not make the function synchronous, it just means that you don't have to keep typing in the `keyword` parameter. You still need to await `getData()`, in order to ensure completion before continuing.

Comment: Thank you! That fix my problem, but some similar situation happen again when I scroll. I post as another answer. If you can help me again I am really appreciate it!

Comment: I think you're struggling with the correct usage of async/await. And I think understanding how that works will get you closer to your goal. So I've added an explainer above.

Comment: Thank you @kim3er, but the result of console still not work as I think even though I add await queryNews(keyword) in scrollHandler() this time. I guess it is because setState to trigger a component re-render? I post as another answer, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to kim3er, that really help.

But simillar situation happened again when I scroll, it console.log("queryNews2"), and then it console "mobile", which means it render the component again, and then go back to queryNews() to finish execute the rest of the function?Why didn't it wait while I already put all the code in

```
getData().then(() => {
      console.log("6");
      window.addEventListener("wheel", scrollHandler);
      console.log("7");
    });
```

Thanks!!

(stack overflow suddenly said I can't embed image now so I paste an image link instead)
[https://imgur.com/a/lDKEzxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7W7hu.png)

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("1");
    if (windowResized === "large" || windowResized === undefined) return;
    let isFetching = false;
    let isPaging = true;
    let paging = 0;

    console.log("2");

    async function queryNews(input: string) {
      console.log("queryNews1");
      isFetching = true;
      setIsLoading(true);
      setSearchState(true);
      setPageOnLoad(true);
      console.log("queryNews2");

      const resp = await index.search(`${input}`, {
        page: paging,
      });
      console.log("queryNews3");

      const hits = resp?.hits as ArticleType[];
      setTotalArticle(resp?.nbHits);
      console.log("queryNews4");

      setArticles((prev) => [...prev, ...hits]);
      console.log("queryNews5");

      setIsLoading(false);
      console.log("queryNews6");

      paging = paging + 1;
      if (paging === resp?.nbPages) {
        isPaging = false;
        setScrolling(true);
        return;
      }

      console.log("queryNews7");

      isFetching = false;
      setSearchState(false);
      setPageOnLoad(false);
      console.log("queryNews8");
    }

    console.log("3");

    async function scrollHandler(e: WheelEvent) {
      if (
        window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >=
        document.body.offsetHeight - 100
      ) {
        if (isFetching || !isPaging) return;
        console.log("scrollHandler");
         getData().then(() => {
           console.log("6");
           window.addEventListener("wheel", scrollHandler);
           console.log("7");
         });
        
      }
    }

     const getData = async () => {
       await queryNews(keyword);
     };

    getData().then(() => {
      console.log("4");
      window.addEventListener("wheel", scrollHandler);
      console.log("5");
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("wheel", scrollHandler);
    };
  }, [keyword, setSearchState, windowResized]);
```

Answer (score 0):

@kim3er
Thank you for your detailed answer, and sorry for my late response.
According to your explanation about difference between async/await and .then(),
I found that I didn't await getData() in scrollHandler(), so I modified my code again, I call queryNews(keyword) this time instead, but then something weird still exist.

The console.log sequence is right when first load(No1~10 in image below),and then when I scroll, I call scrollHandler(), and inside scrollHandler, await queryNews() is executed, but then again,it console to "queryNews2", and then it "jump out" of queryNews() to render component again I guess, because the word "mobile" in JSX tag is console before "queryNews3"(No13~18 in image below).

I use await queryNews(keyword) in scollHandler() this time, but it still has wrong console sequence.Why?Does it has anything to do with setState inside queryNews()?Because as far as I know, setState will trigger a component re-render?

Thank you for answer my question patiently.

[console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/md8Yk.png)

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("1");
    if (windowResized === "large" || windowResized === undefined) return;
    let isFetching = false;
    let isPaging = true;
    let paging = 0;

    console.log("2");

    async function queryNews(input: string) {
      console.log("queryNews1");
      isFetching = true;
      setIsLoading(true);
      setSearchState(true);
      setPageOnLoad(true);
      console.log("queryNews2");

      const resp = await index.search(`${input}`, {
        page: paging,
      });
      console.log("queryNews3");

      const hits = resp?.hits as ArticleType[];
      setTotalArticle(resp?.nbHits);
      console.log("queryNews4");

      setArticles((prev) => [...prev, ...hits]);
      console.log("queryNews5");

      setIsLoading(false);
      console.log("queryNews6");

      paging = paging + 1;
      if (paging === resp?.nbPages) {
        isPaging = false;
        setScrolling(true);
        return;
      }

      console.log("queryNews7");

      isFetching = false;
      setSearchState(false);
      setPageOnLoad(false);
      console.log("queryNews8");
    }

    console.log("3");

    async function scrollHandler(e: WheelEvent) {
      if (
        window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >=
        document.body.offsetHeight - 100
      ) {
        if (isFetching || !isPaging) return;
        console.log("scrollHandler");
        await queryNews(keyword);

        console.log("end scrollHandler");
      }
    }

    queryNews(keyword).then(() => {
      console.log("4");

      window.addEventListener("wheel", scrollHandler);
      console.log("5");
    });
    

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("wheel", scrollHandler);
    };
  }, [keyword, setSearchState, windowResized]);
```